# How can launch phantomJS with arguments in selenium with python?

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

```
service_args = ['--cookies-file=C:\\cookie\\cookies.txt']

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='Z:\\Win7\\python\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe',service_args=service_args)
```

This is my code.I want to enable cookiesfile in phantomJS.But it didn't work.There is no file in cookie folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookie file indeed is not created when PhantomJS's launched with --webdriver option. Seems it's a known bug: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1911